# Why are there backslashes before keywords in this Bash function?

Tags: bash

Why are there backslashes before the `local` and `return` keywords in this Bash function?

```bash
mamba() {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        activate|deactivate)
            __conda_activate "$@"
            ;;
        install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
            __mamba_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate
            ;;
        *)
            __mamba_exe "$@"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: See [How can you use pure unset shell builtin? Can you write shell scripts that are immune to tampering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35916983/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are there backslashes before the `local` and `return` keywords in this Bash function?

To not use aliases. Or more precisely to provide a command name that contains a backslash in the shell code, but represents the command name as `local` or `return` as the word how the interpreter handles it.

This is a marker how the shell has to resolve the command for that name and quotes the the following character which has no other special meaning but for the newline character.

So in your case it is rudimentary equivalent to `local` or `return` by the common understanding.

Cf. *[Escape Character (Backslash)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01)*, *[Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)*

Comment: add details and context please

Comment: @Anil: In addition to the edit you may find more context in the `__add_sys_prefix_to_path()` function in the same file, and if so, then please see [qa73876302](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73876302/22873487 "bash script - why backslash did not escape "d" here in "\dirname" [duplicate]").